# Xaml Trigger Parent via a specific property of any child in Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, datatrigger

I'm having troubles with triggers for a Child-Parent relation in my ViewModel.

Consider the following ViewModel (implements`INotifyPropertyChanged`) and View:

```
ViewModelType
 + Items: ObservableCollection<ViewModelType>
 + IsVisible: bool
 + Text: string

ViewType
 + Visibility: Visibility
 + Header: string
```

I have a DataTemplate to bind the 2:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModelType}">
  <views:ViewType Header="{Binding Text}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And a style for the View:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type views:ViewType}">
  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource Bool2Visibility}}"/>
</Style>
```

This all works beautifully.

Now, what I want to achieve is that if from ViewModelTypeInstanceA *all* `ViewModelType.Items` have their `IsVisible` property set to `false`, I want ViewModelTypeInstanceA corresponding `ViewType` to have its `Visibility` property set to `Visibility.Collapsed`**.

I have tried DataTriggers, converters and all but I don't think I can use something like AncestorType in triggers to non referable parent? It seems impossible to trigger a parent property. Perhaps it's possible for an element to observe all it's children's IsVisisble properties?

Conditions:
1. I prefer to NOT alter the ControlTemplate (it's from a diff lib).
2. Modifying the ViewModel structure isn't an option either (compatibility issues). That means I cannot maintain a property `Parent` on item creation or alter the Collection type as Eli suggested.
3. I really prefer an elegant solution.

**Ofcourse depending on the children's ViewType's VisibilityProperty is also OK, if it can be set through styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the cleanest, but the best that I could think of I guess. I'm (ab)using the physical parent's DataContext.

1. I added a `ViewModelType.HasVisibleChild`-property and a `EvaluateHasVisibleChildValue()` method.

```
internal void EvaluateHasVisibleChild()
{
  foreach(ViewModelType node in Items)
    // Conditions for ultimate visibility
    if (node.IsVisible && node.HasVisibleChild)
    {
      HasVisibleChild = true;
      return;
    }

  HasVisibleChild = false;
}
```

2. I changed the style binding that uses a converter and provides the Visibility-dependent properties both as the physical `ViewType` ancestor:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type views:ViewType}">
  <Setter.Value>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConditionalVisibilityConverter}">
      <Binding Path="IsVisible"/>
      <Binding Path="HasVisibleChild"/>
      <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type views:ViewType}}"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </Setter.Value>
</Style>
```

3. I wrote a MultiBindingConverter:

```
public class ConditionalVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object paramater, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    // Has no ancestor safety check
    if (values[2] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
      // Sneak in an update of viewmodelparent via physical parent.
      (((values[2] as FrameworkElement).DataContext) as ViewModelType).EvaluateHasVisibleChild();

    return (bool)values[0] && (bool)values[1] ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object paramweter, CultureInfo cultuer)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

In practise I have multiple ViewTypes as ancestors, so I added multiple Bindings for various ancestorTypes. I also considered adding an Interface to various the ViewTypes, but nuh-uh.

N.b. this obviously requires that exactly 1 ViewType is used per ViewModelType, otherwise the FindAncestorType might get unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up to the `PropertyChanged` event of every item. You can also inherit from `ObservableCollection` and hook up the event when items are added/removed. Then create a calculated property in the view model and fire its property changed event.

Another option is to use a framework like [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/).

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new NotificationCollection<Item>();
        Items.ItemPropertyChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Item.IsVisible))
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsVisible));
        };
    }

    public NotificationCollection<Item> Items { get; }

    public bool IsVisible => Items.All(i => i.IsVisible);
}
```

If you cannot change the type of the collection, you can use the `CollectionChanged` event:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedHandler = (o, e) =>
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Item.IsVisible))
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsVisible));
};

Items.CollectionChanged += (o, e) =>
{
    if (e.OldItems != null)
        foreach (var item in e.OldItems.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
            item.PropertyChanged -= propertyChangedHandler;
    if (e.NewItems != null)
        foreach (var item in e.NewItems.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
            item.PropertyChanged += propertyChangedHandler;
};
```

And here's the `NotificationCollection` class:

```
public class NotificationCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler ItemPropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemPropertyChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            DisconnectItem(item);
        }
        base.ClearItems();
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        ConnectItem(item);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        DisconnectItem(Items[index]);
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        DisconnectItem(Items[index]);
        base.SetItem(index, item);
        ConnectItem(item);
    }

    private void ConnectItem(T item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void DisconnectItem(T item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Eli Arbel, unfortunately I cannot modify the structure of my ViewModel. I could perhaps add a second collection property that does this job which subscribes to CollectionChanged etc. but I don't consider that very elegant either. Thanks for your effort